# sql join return values incorrect

Tags: sql-server

I have the below scenario

```
create table Ta1 (id int)
create table Ta2 (id int)

insert into Ta1 (id) values (1)
insert into Ta1 (id) values (1)

insert into Ta2 (id) values (1)
insert into Ta2 (id) values (1)
insert into Ta2 (id) values (1)
insert into Ta2 (id) values (1)

select b.id  from Ta1 a ,Ta2 b where a.id=b.id
```

it should return 8 rows with 1. why I think it should return only 4 rows

Thanks
Arun

Comment: On SQL Server 2012 I'm getting 8 rows.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 8 rows as well

Comment: because `2 * 4 = 8`?

Comment: @Bohemian How does the edit not help the question?

Comment: @edrodriguez it wasn't any clearer with your edit. If you edit an unclear question, do more than fix the odd grammar error; for example add some sentences and examples to make the question clear. Be bold!

Comment: "it should return" vs "it returns" does make a difference dear mod @Bohemian

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use the old `JOIN` syntax. It's really hard to read and I'd failed every code check-in at my company that uses that style. You should use this instead:

```
SELECT *
FORM Ta1 a
INNER JOIN Ta2 b ON a.id = b.id
```

Now to answer your question: each of the 2 rows in `Ta1` matches all 4 in `Ta2`. That's why you get `2 x 4 = 8` rows. Every version of SQL Server will give you 8 rows. You are essentially do a Cartesian product on these 2 tables.

Comment: ↑You beat me to it @zoff but yes OP that's basically why you get 8 results